# Add button to right side of screen

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` added to the left side of the screen. I have added it like this:

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
let menuButtonSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 44, height: 44)
func confiureCloseButton() {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: menuButtonSize))
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_close"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        button.center = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 61)
        button.layer.zPosition = 1
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }
```

How can I add another button to the right side?

Comment: The same way but with a different `origin.x` value.

Comment: @rmaddy - The `origin: CGPoint.zero` is 0,0. How do I do it for the right side?

Comment: Change the 1st `0` to the needed number to be where you want it. Better yet, use constraints.

Comment: @rmaddy How do I edit the first 0? Should I change from `CGPoint.zero` to `CGPoint(x: screenSize.width-44, y: 0)`?

Comment: Use constraints. Much better than coding frames.

Comment: @rmaddy Can you provide an example using constrains please?

Comment: Do a Google search on "swift iOS constraints" for countless examples and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
firstBu.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false 
self.view.addSubview(firstBu)  
secondBu.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false 
self.view.addSubview(secondBu)  
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([ 
    firstBu.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor,constant:50), 
    firstBu.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,constant:61), 
    firstBu.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44), 
    firstBu.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44),  
    secondBu.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.firstBu.trailingAnchor,constant:20), 
    secondBu.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.firstBu.centerYAnchor), 
    secondBu.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44), 
    secondBu.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44)
])
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want the button to be a mirror image of the left button:

```
func configureRightButton() {
    let rightButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: menuButtonSize))
    let frameWidth = view.frame.width

    rightButton.center = CGPoint(x: frameWidth - 50, y: 61)
    rightButton.layer.zPosition = 1

    view.addSubview(rightButton)
}
```

Comment: You should not based anything on the screen size. Base it on the size of the view controller's view. Using constraints is even better.